# Replacing innerHTML closes tag unnecessarily in Angular

Tags: html, regex, angular, typescript, dom

I have a function in Angular that takes DOM content and does search and replace to annotate specific text. The problem is that the replaced text (using innerHTML) closes tags prematurely. Simplistically, it is reading:

`}--><p _ngcontent-atr-c1="" class="paragraph-body ng-star-inserted"><div>Blah blah</div></p><!--bindings={`

and thinks the `<p>` is not closed and the `</p>` is not opened, so the innerHTML is inappropriately closing and opening tags automatically like so:

`}--><p _ngcontent-atr-c1="" class="paragraph-body ng-star-inserted"></p><div>Blah blah</div><p></p><!--bindings={`

How do I resolve this?

My function (which looks for case variants of `searchTerm` to replace):

```
startSearch(searchTerm: string) {
    const content = document.getElementById('chapter').children;
    const regexLower = new RegExp(`${searchTerm.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}`, 'g');
    const regexUpper = new RegExp(`${searchTerm.toUpperCase().replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}`, 'g');
    const regexCapitalized = new RegExp(
      `${searchTerm.replace(/^\w/,
      c => c.toUpperCase()).replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}`, 'g'
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      const block = content[i].innerHTML;
      block.replace(regexLower, `<span class="highlight">${searchTerm.toLowerCase()}</span>`);
      block.replace(regexUpper, `<span class="highlight">${searchTerm.toUpperCase()}</span>`);
      block.replace(regexCapitalized, `<span class="highlight">${searchTerm.replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase())}</span>`);
      content[i].innerHTML = block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote without explaining? Asking what you think is a similar question is not a reason to downvote (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled), especially since it's a different description of the similar question referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have malformed HTML according to the web browser.

It's disallowing `<div>` tags inside the `<p>` tag content.

[image]